# How to abbreviate and use repetitive expressions in R

Tags: r

I'm making a code that converts data and labels of SAV file into one XLSX file. In the code, same paths and file names are repeatedly used within functions, so is there a way to define and abbreviate them?

```
library(foreign)
library(xlsx)

data <- read.spss('path/file_name.SAV', use.value.labels=FALSE, to.data.frame=TRUE)
label <- read.spss('path/file_name.SAV', use.value.labels=TRUE, to.data.frame=TRUE)

write.xlsx(data, 'path/file_name.xlsx', sheetName="DATA", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=FALSE, showNA=FALSE)
write.xlsx(label, 'path/file_name.xlsx', sheetName="LABEL", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE, showNA=FALSE)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using variables for path/file names e.g.?

```
fn <- "file_name.SAV"
dr <- "/directory/here/" 
full_path <- paste0(dr, fn)
data <- read.spss(full_path)
```